# Bigquery pricing with Cloud SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have connect to Cloud SQL from Bigquery and using DataStudio too.
I readed about Bigquery pricing but i can't clearly about how to calculate the cost in this case.
In this case do I have to pay for Storage cost?
If so, how will it be calculated? Example If the account only connects to 3 tables in 10 tables in the database. How will it be calculated?
Thank all.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.I did not read the documentation clearly
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_pricing